# Is it possible with kineticjs to render a huge image from a stage of a size of 4% of the image to be rendered?

Tags: javascript, php, image, kineticjs

I'm working on a site where a user can edit a banner for them selves and I'm planning to use kineticJS for the image editor. The thing is, the banner will go for print and the result image has to be 5014px by 12402px. It is possible to have an image sized like that, but the stage size would be only the 4% (200x496) of the final image? If not, what would you suggest to do to render a huge image like that? (I was thinking to generate a data file at the end of editing, then render the image in PHP with GD).

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Just upload the huge image to the server without displaying it on canvas.

If you need to give the user visual feedback you can resize the image in PHP and send back the 4% image for Kinetic to display.

Here's a link to a php resizer:  http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php

BTW, 60M+ upload exceeds the default limits of PHP server so be sure you reconfigure your server!

Comment: Hi Mark! The thing is, my client wants their visitors to edit their own banners on the website (like a t-shirt editor on many websites). But since this whole thing has to go to print, that's the sucky part :/ That's why I need to have that huge res image. And I'm not even talking about the DPI resolution :( Thank you for your advice, I'll keep it in mind and if I can proceed to a good way with this project, I'll like it for you ;)

Comment: There is no computer screen as large as 5014px by 12402px so the user will *always* be working on a smaller version on the website.  Having created posters, I know your printer needs the larger full-sized image to do the actual printing.  What I'm suggesting is that the user upload the full sized image.  Your php server saves that image and returns a reduced size image for the user to mark up on the website.  When the user completes their design, just their additions are uploaded and php combines the users design to the full-sized image.

Answer (score 0):

Weeell, if you can restrict your users to use shapes only to draw their content you could serialize the stage and convert it to a vector format.
Then you can render this vector format to whatever size of bitmap you want.
But that's quite a project...